# Retrieving arbitrary Eclipse preferences programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I am writing [a plugin for Pig files](https://github.com/eyala/pig-eclipse). I would like to retrieve the Eclipse "file associations" preference - the one under General -> Editors -> File Associations -> File Types / Associated Editors.

Once I have this preference, my plugin can know which file types are being used, and act accordingly when iterating over the workspace files (in searches and the like).

I couldn't find a "directory" of preferences anywhere, nor an API that I could iterate over until I found it. Searching the file system of my workspace didn't seem to work either - possibly the preferences are being held in a binary format.

1) What is the key for retrieving this preference from the PreferenceStore?

2) What is the best way, in general, for finding the key for a given preference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
IFileEditorMapping[] mapping = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getEditorRegistry().getFileEditorMappings();
```

to get the mappings between file types and their supported editors.  Look [at this javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IFileEditorMapping.html) to see everything you could ever want to know about the mappings

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to give you some hint, someone may have a better solution :

1 : id `org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages.ContentTypes`

2 : Use the Plug-ins Spy `Press Alt-Shift-F1` on the desire page/widget on eclipse, it will display contextual informations

Answer (score 1):

There is no overall API which will give you all the preferences.

Many preferences are stored in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` directory in 'plugin-id.prefs' files (Java Property file format). You can access these with

```java
IEclipsePreferences prefs = InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("plugin id");

String value = prefs.get("preference id", defaultValue);
```

So you need to know the id of the plugin that owns the preference and the id of the preference itself. This information can be difficult to find and may involve reading the source of the preference page.

Other preferences are stored in the Eclipse `configuration` directory. Yet others are in some format only known to a particular plugin (but there is usually some API to access the information).